# Convert 32 bit binary number to decimal

Tags: java, ieee-754

someone who can help me I have the following drawback,
  to enter a negative decimal binary in this case enter -20 (11000001101000000000000000000000) throws me the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000001101000000000000000000000"

```
# Include  <stdio.h> 
# include  <stdlib.h>

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    int bits = Integer.parseInt("1000001101000000000000… 2);        
    float f1 = Float.intBitsToFloat(bits);
    int Sign = ((bits >> 31) == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int Exponent = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff);
    int Mantissa = (Exponent== 0)
    ? (bits & 0x7fffff) << 1
    : (bits & 0x7fffff) | 0x800000;
    System.out.println("Sign: " + Sign + " Exponent: " + Exponent + "Mantissa:" + Mantissa);
    System.out.println(f1);
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase in English.

Comment: +1. Thanks @David for translating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Integer.#parseInt(java.lang.String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> ...The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) **returns a nonnegative value**)...

Unfortunately you want to parse negative value. You could try using `Long.parseLong` instead and cast returned `long` to `int`

```
int bits = (int) Long.parseLong("11000001101000000000000000000000", 2);
```

This way you will get your int that has same byte representation

```
System.out.println(">"+Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
```

output:

```
>11000001101000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks I worked took 15 days looking for him the jokes but nothing.Gracias Mil gracias me funciono llevo 15 dias buscandole el chistes pero nada